# Paypal Credit Card Payment without login (no paypal account)

Tags: paypal, payment

Can Paypal Express checkout integration include a payment way with credit card which do not require customer to login  to paypal or to create a new paypal account?

Comment: Yes, you need to enable it in your merchant account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Express Checkout supports guest checkout (payer without PayPal account). You need to set SOLUTIONTYPE=sole in your SetExpressCheckout API, and also set "PayPal Account Optional" to "on" in your PayPal account -> [Profile] -> [My selling tools] -> [Website preferences] .
Please also be noted that PayPal will check the security of the network environment of the payer. And as a result, there is still some possibility that no guest checkout option is available for some payers.